# Cannot access Ubuntu 16.04 machine remotely

Tags: networking, server, ssh, firewall

I am trying to set up the machine so that I can ssh into it from anywhere. I'm running on Ubuntu 16.04.1 I can access the server perfectly from the local network (tested on 2 machines). I cannot ssh, ping or traceroute from outside the network. ssh times out, ping fails and traceroutes will fail (the online service suggests this may be a firewall issue)

So far I have set up openssh to be listening on port 7999

```
> service ssh status

... Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 7999. ...

> nmap localhost -p 7999
PORT     STATE SERVICE
7999/tcp open  irdmi2
```

I've checked the firewall on the machine

```
> sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

**EDIT:**

I've tried googling "whats my ip" and pinging that ipv4 address, but all packets are lost. I've also tried tracerouting that address both locally and from an online service. Locally I get all stars. Through the online service once it gets 3 hops of stars it assumes it has reached a firewall.

I think I've set up port forwarding on my router, though I have not verifed it is working. I'm not sure how to verify it or what to do next.

Comment: Next verify port forwarding is working on your router.

Comment: Also check that you're using the correct IP address for your router, if it's assigned by an ISP it may be dynamic, so subject to change.

Comment: I'm not sure how to check port warding is working as intended, since I can't see the router from outside the network. How would I check that I have the correct ip for the router? Editted the question to include the pinging steps I took.

Comment: Go to http://www.canyouseeme.org/ and put in port 7999